# How can I update the top left position after resizing a rotated object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, trigonometry

I have an object that can be resized by any of its 4 sides as well as any of its 4 corners.

Now I'm trying to make it rotatable and I'm doing so with the CSS property `translate: rotate(angle)`, with the anchor being the center of the object.

The object has the properties top, left, width, height and angle.

The problem is that once it's rotated, if I need to resize it from the bottom-right corner for example, it doesn't maintain its top-left position while still keeping the center anchor point.

I need to find a way to maintain the top-left position by updating it, probably with some trigonometry.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("object");

  console.log(obj.style.top, obj.style.left); // 100, 100

  obj.style.width = "200px";
  obj.style.height = "200px";

  // Something needs to be done here to update the top left position and keep it in place

});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="object"></div>
<button id="button">Resize bottom-right corner</button>
```

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/04L5rho8/2/)

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the thingy that appears after clicking the button.

Comment: That's just a sample code to demonstrate the problem. The actual code is written in React and there's too much dependency to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to make it stay in place, so just add:

```
obj.style.left = "25px";
obj.style.top = "25px";
```

after setting the height and width.
To get the position, I saw you made it go from 50 to 200 pixels in size (4x increase) so I made it one fourth of original x/y putting it in the "same" spot.

Hope this helps! (codepen: http://codepen.io/JohnJ1101/pen/wJpJqE)

Comment: Not as simple as that. I want the top-left corner to stay in position, so I need a formula to get the new top and left positions to make it stay if I pull the bottom-right corner as well as if I pull in the opposite direction or any other direction.

Comment: try setting transform-origin to 0% 0%

Comment: I can't change the center anchor point. Because I should be able to pull the object from any of its 8 points to resize it.